# Jquery - Multi-Unbind

Tags: jquery, unbind

what is the best way to unbind all?

For example
i start a function `someName('mp3Player')`

in this function are many binds

```
function someName(mode)
{
  if(mode == 'exit')
  {
    $('#player').remove();
    // unbind all 
    // ..........
    return true;
  }  

  if(mode == 'mp3Player')
  {
     $('body').append('<div id="player"> *** add some html code *** </div>');
     $('#test').draggable ....
     $('.myLi').sortable ....
     $('myButton').click ....
     $('.dragable').live( "dragstop", function (event, ui) ....
     return true;
  }

}
```

Any good ideas?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `unbind` or `die`

[`jquery unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

[`jquery die`](http://api.jquery.com/die/)

in your case you are `live` bunding`the event so its better/necessary to use`die` as

```
$('.dragable').die('dragstop');
```

to unbind single event as maxedison mentioned do

```
$("element").unbind("eventName");
```

this will unbind the event attached to the element to unbind all the events attached to an element call unbind without any arguments

```
$("selector").unbind();
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it would be to simply call something like the following on each element:

```
$('mySelector').unbind('eventName');
```

For example:

```
$('.myButton').unbind('click');
```